# MYSQL select comments, limit 3, 'click to see all' and display on same page. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, click, limit

I have some code which retrieves user comments from my database:

```
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID'LIMIT 0, 3;")
  or die(mysql_error());

while ($rowC = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) {
  echo "<p>On " .$rowC['date']. ", ";
  echo $rowC['username']. " said: <br/>";
  echo $rowC['comment'];
  echo "</p><hr/>";
}
if (mysql_num_rows($comments) == 0) { 
  echo "<p>(No comments have been made yet)</p>"; 
}
```

Comments are stored with a unique user reference in the database, and retrieved where they match the user id, this is called at the top of the page:

```
$theID = $_GET['id'];
```

What I am trying to do is limit the comments shown, and if there are more than 3, show a 'click to see more' type button or link which displays all the user comments on the same page in the same way as above.

UPDATE, i am now using this, Trying to implement Johan's suggestion, but still cant get it to display more when link is clicked:

```
  $comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID' LIMIT 0, 4") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($rowC = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) {
      echo "<p>On " .$rowC['date']. ", ";
      $username = htmlspecialchars($rowC['username']). " said: <br/>";
        echo $username;
        $comment = htmlspecialchars($rowC['comment']);
        echo $comment;
      echo "</p><hr/>";
    }

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 3) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID' LIMIT 4, 20";
    } echo "<p><a href=''>click to see more</a></p>";

    if (mysql_num_rows($comments) == 0) { 
      echo "<p>(No comments have been made yet)</p>"; 
    }
```

Comment: simply do it with PHP and jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?

if($_GET['allcomments'] == 1 && preg_match("/([0-9]+)/", $_GET['id'])){

   $comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '".$_GET['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());

   for($c=0; ($rowC = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) !== FALSE; $c++) {
       echo "<p>On " .$rowC['date']. ", ";
       echo htmlentities($rowC['username']). " said: <br/>";
       echo htmlentities($rowC['comment']);
       echo "</p><hr/>";
   }

}else{


$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID' LIMIT 0, 4;" ) or die(mysql_error());

for($c=0; ($rowC = mysql_fetch_array($comments)) !== FALSE; $c++) {
    echo "<p>On " .$rowC['date']. ", ";
    echo htmlentities($rowC['username']). " said: <br/>";
    echo htmlentities($rowC['comment']);
    echo "</p><hr/>";
    if($c == 3){
       echo "<p><a href='?allcomments=1&id=$theID'>click to see more</a></p>";
       break;
    }
}

if (!$c) { 
   echo "<p>(No comments have been made yet)</p>";
}

}
?>
```

I consider that $theID variable contains only digits from 0 to 9. If not, change the regular expression (preg_match).

Comment: @bitfox, you have a XSS security hole in `echo $rowC['comment'];`

Comment: Tried this, displays link, but doesn't display anymore comments when clicked, when user ref in database is over 10, it still only displays 4 comments.

Comment: @Johan: About XSS security hole... I modified the code by adding htmlentities function. I supposed that the comments were sanitized before during the INSERT operation, so the data into database must be sanitized.

@user736338: Ok... so, you want the visualization of all comments, too. No problem, I'll update the code in a few minutes :-)

Comment: @bitbox, you forgot to sanitize the `username`:-) you're making assumptions that are not likely to be valid, looking at the problems in the OP's code.

Comment: @Johan: Now, also the username is sanitized. My assumptions start by consider previous checks which must be done in well written code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yikes: You have a couple of error/issues.

**SQL-injection**

```
$theID = $_GET['id'];
```

Fix this to

```
$theID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

To get rid of a gaping SQL-injection hole.
See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

**XSS vulnerability**

Replace this code:

```
echo $rowC['username']. " said: <br/>";
echo $rowC['comment'];
```

With this

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($rowC['username']). " said: <br/>";
echo $username;
$comment = htmlspecialchars($rowC['comment']);
echo $comment;
```

See: [Do htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string keep my PHP code safe from injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-injec)
And: [When is it Best to Sanitize User Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896/when-is-it-best-to-sanitize-user-input)

**Error in code**
Change this:

```
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID'LIMIT 0, 3;")
```

To this

```
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID' LIMIT 0, 3")
```

**Back to the question**

if you change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID' LIMIT 0, 4"
```

Then you can check the number of results returned. If it's 4 then display the `more...` button.

Use this query to get 20 more results

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if $num_rows > 3 {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ref = '$theID' LIMIT 4, 20";
  ...
```