# Bypass HTML Encoding/Escaping for XSS

Tags: javascript, html, xss

When you publish a map in a game called "Fortnite" it asks for a name, a description, and an optional Youtube video. What I'm trying to do is set the "description" to a script tag. Inspect the description on the [site here](http://epicgames.com/fn/1222-0331-8814) and edit as html to see the encoding that happens, The description that you input is set to that island-header-tagline h3 tag

And I'm trying to run a `<script>` tag on an `<h3>` tag. However it seems that when I try to inject the script tag into the h3 tag it html encodes it (`<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`). So it doesn't actually recognize it as an html tag and doesn't run the script. Does anyone know how this would be achieved? Thank you.

Edit: Here is what I'm trying to achieve: Say this is the where the input goes: `<h3>USER INPUT</h3>`. I'm trying to do something like this `<h3></h3><script>alert('test');</script>` However `<` and `>` are escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

P.S.: I'm learning XSS (For non-malicious purposes)

Comment: It would be much clearer if you showed us the code you're using to try and achieve this

Comment: Sorry, so say this is the where the input goes: `<h3>USER INPUT</h3>`. I'm trying to do something like this `<h3></h3><script>alert('test');</script>` However < and > are escaped to &lt; and &gt;    EDIT: As for how the script gets inside the <h3> tag, it's a generated page and the input is set to there on generation.

Comment: Yes but _how_ are you injecting it? Hard-coded? Or using some server side script? Also please add extra code/info via the "edit" button of your question, not via comments. You can comment to let people know you've done it, though

Comment: Sorry again, edited and added that code. As for the injection. The page is generated through a program with a unique id (eg `www.example.com/{{id}}`) And the input is automatically added into that h3 tag and collected by the generation program. Hope that's enough, I might not be understanding you correctly if not

Comment: "The page is generated through a program" what program? written in what language ?

Comment: Ok I'll just explain as much as I can, When you publish a map in a game called "Fortnite" it asks for a name, a description, and an optional Youtube video. What I'm trying to do is set the "description" to a script tag. Inspect the description on the site here (https://epicgames.com/fn/1222-0331-8814) and edit as html to see the encoding that happens, The description that you input is set to that `island-header-tagline` h3 tag.

Comment: @dash that comment is very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that Fortnite asks for "title", and you provide title in the form of HTML code, such as:

```
 <script>alert('test');</script>
```

Then Fortnite web-server accepts that text, and, for security reasons, cleans it up. This is done to protect end users from people who would try to insert code like

```
 <script>StealAllTheMoney();</script>
```

This is also called "[sanitization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896/when-is-it-best-to-sanitize-user-input)" of user inputs. We do that in order to protect end-users and our web-server. Unless there is a vulnerability on the Fortnite's side, there is nothing you can do to bypass that sanitization as it [escapes some characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) that can be part of malicious inputs. In your case it is at least ">".

Comment: Thank you! I guess Fortnite is doing a good job with their security, I still don't know a lot about xss so I appreciate the answer!